# Sorting a mutable array using a dictionary key

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary, mutable

I am trying to create a simple mutable array with a single key ("dayCounter") that I intend to use for sorting.  I've read loads of examples on line, but no joy.

So I create this array.  Note the first entry is a NSDictionary object. (The other objects are text)

```
cumArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dayCounter] forKey:@"dayCounter"],[[dailyArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:0],[[dailyArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:1],[[dailyArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:2], nil],nil];
```

I save the array in a plist and everything looks great after the load.

However, when I come to sort the array, the program crashes. I have tried every combination of the following:

```
        NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dayCounter" ascending:YES];
        [cumArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Do I need a dictionary item to act as a key?  Can I sort on the first object any easier?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you want to rename the array, haha, cumArray

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using too many nested expressions can obscure what's really going on. For example, the 'simple' mutable array you created actually contains a nested mutable array, rather than directly containing the dictionaries you're trying to sort.

So instead of this:

```
cumArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dayCounter] forKey:@"dayCounter"],[[dailyArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:0],[[dailyArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:1],[[dailyArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:2], nil],nil];
```

try doing this

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dayCounter]
                                                  forKey:@"dayCounter"]
NSArray *objs = [dailyArray objectAtIndex:x];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [objs objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *dict3 = [objs objectAtIndex:1];
NSDictionary *dict4 = [objs objectAtIndex:2];

// Note: You might want to temporarily log the values of dict2 - 4 here to make sure they're
// really dictionaries, and that they all actually contain the key 'dayCounter'.

cumArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, nil];
```

Assuming that you really have a mutable array of dictionaries, each of which contains the key `dayCounter`, the sort descriptor you showed in your example should work just fine.

Comment: Hi jlehr.  I'm only wanting to sort on the first 'field' (object) in a four object array.  I thought I had to make the first object a key by using a dictionary object.  I'm happy just to sort a regular array that had no dictionary objects if I could.  Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Your setup makes no sense. You are saying yourself that only the first object in the array is a dictionary that contains the key `@"dayCounter" ("The other objects are text"). How is it supposed to be sorted if only one object contains the sort criteria?

Comment: Hi Ole,  I agree with you.  I'm not sure I need a dictionary object at all.  I really want an array with four objects and then to sort on the first object.  I thought I had to make the first object a "key" i.e. a dictionary object.  So how do I sort on a non-dictionary (regular array) object?

Comment: What you say still makes no sense to me. How can you sort an array on the first object? Suppose I have an array that looks like this: `["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"]`. What sense would it make to sort it on the first object?

Answer (score -1):

You need to sort the array with a method, like - (NSComparisunResult)compareDict
If you have to compare 2 dictionaries and determine which one should be ordered above the other ( NSOrderedAscending ) then you need to "extend" NSDictionary:

```
@interface NSDictionary (SortingAdditions) {}
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTo:(NSDictionary *)other;
@end
@implementation NSDictionary (SortingAddictions)
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTo:(NSDictionary *)other
{
  if( [self count] > [other count] )
  { return NSOrderedAscending; }
}
@end
```

This method will sort NSDictionaries according to the amount of objects that they contain.
Other values you can return here are: NSOrderedDescending and NSOrderedSame.

Then you can sort the mutable array with:

```
[SomeMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareTo:)];
```

Keep in mind that every object in the array will need to be an NSDictionary, otherwise you will get an exception: unrecognized selector sent to instance blabla

You can do the same thing for any type of object, if the array contains both NSStrings, NSNumbers and NSDictionaries you should take a different approach

Comment: There's no reason this won't work with an `NSSortDescriptor`. The problem the OP was having was due to the data being structured incorrectly.